# iOS 7 Background Timer

Tags: ios, background

I have an app (iOS 7+) in which I need to call a webservice after "n" minutes(always greater than 3 ) once the app goes in background. After the call to that webservice is made in need to call another webservice every 45 seconds.

The call for the webservice requires current location of the user. So i am taking the users location and I have a corresponding entry in the `info.plist` file as well.

I have the following code in `applicationdidEnterBackground`

```
CLLocationManager * manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;

background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {
    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

}];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [manager startUpdatingLocation];

    while(TRUE)
    {
        //backgroundTimeRemaining time does not go down.

        NSLog(@"Background time Remaining: %f",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]; //wait for 1 sec
    }

    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});
```

Can you please help me as to how I can run the app in background for "n" minutes which is always greater than 3.

Answer (score 0):

Refer background fetch handler. with some limitation it can help you.